# Fun with Letters, Words and Sentences?

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking, optimization, word-property

I have a game, but first, I need to explain how it works.

Take a sentence, completely meaningful. Suppose the sentence is, "**Yes, yesterday we ate the meal sometime at night**". 
In this sentence, if you take two consecutive words, you will find that both of those words contain a common letter. (For example, the words "**we**" and "**ate**" both have the common letter "**e**")

So, can you find the longest sentence that can exist like this so that :- 
i) The sentence should be meaningful , i.e. , every words and the sentence itself should have a complete meaning. 
ii) Whenever two consecutive words are chosen, there will be at-least a common letter present to them. 
iii) The common letter found between two consecutive words should each be in different positions of the words. This to avoid simple loop holes in sentences like "**"I dislike dummies, donkeys, dancers, deers, dreams and deserts"**" [mentioned by @Lukas Rotter in the comments]

**Bonus** :- Can you find the longest sentence such that :-

i) The sentence should be meaningful , i.e. , every words and the sentence itself should have a complete meaning. 
ii) Whenever any two words/letters are chosen, there will be at-least a common letter present to them. 
iii) The common letter found between two words should each be in different positions of the words. This to avoid simple loop holes in sentences like "**"I dislike dummies, donkeys, dancers, deers, dreams and deserts"**" [mentioned by @Lukas Rotter in the comments]

I hope this will be fun, I will make a leaderboard of the longest sentences possible :) .

**Notes**:-

a) All types of Sentences are acceptable, the only thing is that it should be meaningful some way or the other. You cannot choose a sentence like "**Tomorrow we went to play with our friends.**" because it does not make sense, "**tomorrow**" means something will happen at the future and you cannot use the word "**went**" with it.

b) Note that single-letters are also acceptable in the sentence, in that case while choosing two consecutive words, you have to choose one word and one letter. In the sentence "**I was taking a shower**" , you need to check both the word "**taking**" and the letter "**a**" , or the letter "I" and the word "**was**" , and check if the word you have has the particular letter common or not. In this case the word "**was**" does not contain an "**I**" , so the sentence does not follow the rule.

Comment: What stops me from constructing a sentence with a listing like "I dislike a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i and j" where a-j all just share e.g. the letter 'd'? Would be a meaningful sentence, and if it is it's probably not the only loop hole you could find here.

Comment: @LukasRotter do they have a common letter? No right? "a" is not the same as "b" . "Dislike" has no letter common to "a" , i.e. , "Dislike" does not contain the letter "a" , given that you choose two consecutive letters or words.

Comment: That's not what I meant... a and b are just placeholders. For example: "I dislike dummies, donkeys, dancers, deers, dreams and deserts"

Comment: @LukasRotter ok uh I get it, I would then provide a rule that the common letter formed between two consecutive words should be in different positions of that word.

Comment: I don't think that solves the problem, frankly. Because also I despise seeds, deers, mead, odors and leaders (etc). Sorry that I have to be so annoying :)

Comment: How about you suggest a way to avoid these things and make the puzzle interesting? :)

Comment: @Anonymous That the common letter be different for each couple of words?

Comment: @xhienne yes, actually.

Comment: Also downvoters, please explain these long sets of downvotes. I tried to make one puzzle, and as @LukasRotter pointed out a defect, I definitely don't expect to get 4 downvotes like this.

Comment: I'm not sure one could to that in a good way @anon. Xhiennes suggestion would still work with a seamingly endless list of words. If you prohibit listings themselves it's hard to draw the line (is eg "daniel and dana answered... a listing?) and as I mentioned there are probably more clever loopholes

Comment: Please don't delete your puzzle and then undelete it!

Comment: @LukasRotter how about avoiding the use of commas' and avoiding the use of conjunctions?

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget This puzzle already got downvoted and I don't think keeping it like this will help anyway.

Comment: @Lukas My suggestion cannot lead to an endless list of words. The maximum length of a valid answer would be 27 words (26 couple of words with 26 different common letters)

Comment: @xhienne Ah, sorry, I misunderstood your suggestion as just "consecutive words don't have the same common letter"

Comment: If you have to make so many rules to stop defects, it's going to become boring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like the general idea behind this, however, with enough effort someone could probably create an essay.

** The above follows the rules (I think). 17 words. :-)

Comment: "I like the general idea behind this, however, with enough effort someone could probably create an essay that touches on ornaments." 20 words. And, you're probably right, you could just keep expanding on and on!

Comment: You are probably right @ChromaticRanger. In 1969, French writer Georges Perec wrote the novel ["La Disparition"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Void) which doesn't use the vowel E. E being the most common letter in French, this is much harder, and yet his book is 300 pages long.